# Windows 10 technical preview: Windows can't be installed because this pc uses a compressed operating system

Tags: installation, windows-installation, windows-10-preview

I am trying to upgrade to the Windows 10 technical preview, however when I do, it says that I can't because I am using a compressed OS. What does this mean?

My build:
Intel i7
Windows 8.1 Pro for Razer
8gb ram
1TB SSD (890GB free)

I am installing via the ISO

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Windows 8.1 Pro for Razer - is this preinstalled?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It is what the laptop says on the license key sticker. A Dell PC would say "Windows 8.1 for Dell"

Comment: is your current Windows 8.1 configured as WIMBoot? This may cause the error. In this case, create a bootable DVD/USB drive from the ISO, boot from the WIn10 Installation media, format the drive and do a clean install

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, according to Disk Management,  it is enabled to run as Wim Boot

Comment: boot a live Linux DVD and copy the WIM to an external drive. Later you can extract the WIM with DISM to a clean partition. Boot this partition and upgrade this Windows. Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981  I can create a partition in Disk Management and install to that partition, however, I want all my drivers to be kept and installed on the Windows 10 partition also.

Comment: there are 3rd party tools to backup all current install drivers. Try on of them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my drive to start with.

As @magicandre1981 say, make a bootable drive (just copy stuff on a usb stick and you shound be good to go)

then boot up from the usbstick and start the install

format your drive you want windows on, and you should be up and running on the install. (:

Comment: Cant do this: Some Razer hardware drivers, including ones that control then fan, came with my PC. I once tried putting Windows 7 on my PC and the fans were so loud, I could actually hear then when I was playing games, not to mention graphics performance was down even though I had Nvidia drivers installed.


Needed to restore from BIOS partition

Comment: Allright, that i didn't know. (:
Then my answer is indeed invalid (:

Comment: which one of the razor blade systems do yo have?, just to clarify drivers and suchs.
http://drivers.razersupport.com//index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=402&pcid=271&nav=0,271
chipset drivers for win 8.1 should work for win 10 as well.